# Meaning of "is the same size and"

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

The following sentence comes from https://android.googlesource.com/trusty/app/storage/

> The key value is a hash of the file name and is the same size and the
> block number size for the file system.

Does "is the same size and the block number size for the file system." mean 1)The key value is the same with block number size
Or 2) "Every key value is the same size. And it is the block number size."?

Which interpret is right? Why the author use "same size **and**" here not "same with"?

Comment: No, "Is the same size" does not mean "are all the same size." You may be right that you found a typo: "Is the same size **as** the block number size."

Comment: I agree with @YosefBaskin, it should be "as".  If the block number is a 32-bit field, then the key value is also a 32-bit field.

Comment: I also agree with @YosefBaskin. The hashing algorithm used to produce the key value is written in such a way as to  produce a key of the same length regardless of the length of the file name. The word **and** is a typo for **as**, everyone makes masttooks, sorry, mistakes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a simple typo (as stated to OP in the comment thread in May 2021) and therefore very unlikely to be of use to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a typo for:

> The key value is a hash of the file name and is the same size **as** the block number size for the file system.